# How to get all lists and document libraries in subsite

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, client-object-model

What I want to achieve now is to retrieve all document libraries and lists in sub sites with links to those libraries via JavaScript.
So I can add them to my Page Layout to be like Side Nav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is sample code which shows how to loop through sub sites and lists. Note that it is not tested. However, it will give you a head start:

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = clientContext.get_web();
var webCollection = web.get_webs();
var lists;
clientContext.load(webCollection);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onGetSubwebsSuccess, onGetSubwebsFail);
function onGetSubwebsSuccess(){
var webEnumerator = webCollection.getEnumerator();
while (webEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var web = webEnumerator.get_current();
    // Now iterate through lists in this web
    lists = clientContext.get_web().get_lists();
    clientContext.load(lists, "Include(DefaultViewUrl)");
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onListSuccess, onListFail); 
    }
}

function onListSuccess() {
var listEnumerator = lists.getEnumerator();
    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var list = listEnumerator.get_current();
        var listUrl = list.get_defaultViewUrl();
    }
}
```

Also note that `SP.Web.get_webs();`

> Gets a Web site collection object that represents all Web sites
>   immediately beneath the Web site, excluding children of those Web
>   sites.

**UPDATE**
In order to build the list Url, try:

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + list.get_defaultViewUrl();
```

Comment: everything work but a very important thing ServerRelativeUrl
when i incude it i get error the field or property does not exist

http://pastebin.com/uMv1AF0K

Comment: if i added the title to the web url is that a right way to do it ?

Comment: See my updated answer `_spPageContextInfo` is an OOB SharePoint object which contains lots of useful information.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/S1GTeh9r

that worked for me through list.get_rootFolder()
and through the rootFolder serverRelativeUrl was there

Thank you so much @Nadeem 

you r the most helpful

Comment: I think in my presentation inshalla i'll mention your name 
you have helped me a lot

Comment: Glad I could help. All the best for your presentation.